# CoreData related issue?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have a question related to **CoreData**,

I have this .xcdatamodeld file which has 2 entities, *RCHTask* and *RCHTaskType*

[image: RCHTask]
[image: RCHTaskType]

RCHTask has **many to one** relationship with RCHTaskType

RCHTaskType has **one to many** relationship with RCHTask

I'm trying to fetch instances of RCHTask which has a specific taskType
But I am failing at it I tried this:

```
- (NSArray *)returnTaskOfType:(NSString *)type
{
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *e = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RCHTask"
                                     inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

request.entity = e;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"taskType == %@", type];

request.predicate = predicate;

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request
                                              error:&error];

return result;
}
```

but not working can you tell me how to do it please?

Comment: Please add more detail than "not working", but for a start if you want tasks why are you querying for task types?

Comment: sorry I was trying and left the wrong entity :/ but I got the answer thanks anyways :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the name of the relationship.  Then amend your code to fetch Tasks, and specify the predicate using the relationship name:

```
- (NSArray *)returnTaskOfType:(NSString *)type
{
NSFetchRequest *request = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];

NSEntityDescription *e = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"RCHTask"
                                     inManagedObjectContext:self.context];

request.entity = e;

NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"relationship.taskType == %@", type];

request.predicate = predicate;

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *result = [self.context executeFetchRequest:request
                                              error:&error];

return result;
}
```